# ternery operation returning false everytime - REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, conditional-operator, react-state

I have a state declared and a function to modify that state onClick. It goes like this.

```js
 const [sdgs, setSdgs] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (sdg) => {
    if (sdgs.includes(sdg)) {
      const index = sdgs.indexOf(sdg);
      if (index > -1) {
        setSdgs([...sdgs.slice(0, index), ...sdgs.slice(index + 1)]);
      }
    } else {
      setSdgs([...sdgs, sdg]);
    }
  };
```

And this is called when clicked on an image

```
<img
  src={no_poverty_1}
  alt="No Poverty"
  name="sdg1"
  className={`${style.sdgTileSignUp} mx-2 my-4 ${
   sdgs.indexOf("sdg1") > -1 ? style.selected : null
  }`}
  onClick={() => handleClick("sgd1")}
/>
```

So, what i was going for is onClick i want to add a class "selected" to the image tag. But somehow everytime the ternery operation returns `false`.

Comment: handleClick("s`g`d1")

sdgs.indexOf("s`d`g1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a typo. `sgd` instead of `sdg`.
Sorry and thanks!